# How to use typescript in go

Tags: typescript, go

I am trying to create an Angular app which uses a golang REST API server. There are some business logics which are written in typescript used in front-end. Some of these need to be used in the back-end. To avoid writing the same logic in golang, I was wondering if it is possible to run typescript code in golang? I found SWIG to run C++ code in golang but I did not find anything for typescript. I am aware that I can run golang code in Angular using webassembly or other tools but I am not allowed to write those codes in golang.

Comment: Running TypeScript (JavaScript) in Go would require an interpreter. These exist, but note that it's probably going to be slower, consume more memory, and be harder to use than it would to just write it in Go.

Comment: Ok I understand that the front-end is not the best place for a busines logic. But I don't understand your task. If you move the business logic from the browser to the server I think there is still a lot of to do at the front-end.

Comment: @Adrian I know it is better to write in Go. We would like to do some work like field validation in both Client and Server and the logic is essentially the same. I was hoping to avoid code duplication as it would be harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the duplicated logic in [AssemblyScript](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript), a strict subset of TypeScript, compile it to WebAssembly, and then run it in Go with a runtime like [Wasmer](https://github.com/wasmerio/go-ext-wasm).

Keep in mind though that AssemblyScript is still under development.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [MetaCall](https://github.com/metacall/core), a library that provides inter-language foreign function interfaces which I've been working on it during several years. Basically it allows you to call TypeScript functions from Go without using WebAssembly. The calls are done in the same process so you can still get good performance and use standard TypeScript instead a subset of the language.

The TypeScript support is still under development but you can see a working example of calling TypeScript functions from Go [here](https://github.com/metacall/golang-typescript-example).

With this approach you probably can create a common repository or npm package with the TypeScript logic as a library, and then import it in the Front-end and Back-end at the same time.

You can install MetaCall following [this instructions](https://github.com/metacall/install). Once you have it installed, you can import your npm package in your Go project by using:

```sh
metacall npm install your-package
```

Or adding it with git as a [sub-module](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Later on you can import the TypeScript library as in the [example](https://github.com/metacall/golang-typescript-example/blob/a4c8b47d57b3ff6f6bc6d9c20b3a9cc55553a383/main.go#L21). You do not need to transpile it, MetaCall will take care of it. Remember to [import MetaCall](https://github.com/metacall/golang-typescript-example/blob/a4c8b47d57b3ff6f6bc6d9c20b3a9cc55553a383/main.go#L6) in your Go code and run `go mod tidy`.

Just as a reminder, the example compiles MetaCall by hand, and the install script downloads a pre-built version.